# How to get value from input and comper value with local storage data to make email does not repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, css

> container[i].input_email)   /*this value from loacl storage */

```
function validEmail() {
for (var i = 0; i < container.length; i++) {

    console.log(container[i].input_email);   
    if(container[i].input_email==input_email.value){

        var element = document.getElementById("warnig");
        element.innerHTML = 'email exiest';
        
    }
   
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if I understood right, you would check if the email input value is stored in localStorage and, if so, display a message that says email address already used...right?

```html
<body>
<form>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    <span class="message" style="display: block; font-weight: 700;"></span>
</form>
</body>
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const emailInput = document.querySelector('input');
const message = document.querySelector('.message');

function submitEmail() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('email') === emailInput.value) {
        message.style.color = 'red';
        message.textContent = 'sorry email already exists';
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('email', emailInput.value);
        message.style.color = 'green';
        message.textContent = 'email saved corectly';
    }

}

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    submitEmail();
});
```